# Focus+context based zoom for multiple graphs in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph

I have 'n' graphs in my webpage(single). Now I have the requirement to add a common bar which is responsible for zooming all the graphs at a time and the onclick() event on any graph results in a vertical line cutting all the graphs..!!!

I got no idea how to do this stuff, so no code from my side. Sorry about that. But yes, the graph part has been covered and I am able to display all the graphs based on user selection.

Please help me out with these two requirements or any links or pointers would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've seen this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) right?  In the `brushed` callback:

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

It's setting an `x` domain, applying that to an axis of a plot and redrawing an area chart of a plot.

Just extend this:

```
function brushed() {
  // shared x domain of plots, update extent
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  // adjust plot 1
  plot1.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  plot1.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  // adjust plot 2
  plot2.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  plot2.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, Thanks for your time and suggestion, but it doesnt seem to solve my problem. I need a common slider which can facilitate zooming to all the graphs simultaneously